# python check if a window/app is in full screen in a multi-monitor setup

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, window, fullscreen

The script would constantly go through all the opened, visible windows and check if any of them are full screen in any monitor.

For example, in a dual monitor setup, I might full screen a youtube video on monitor A, and the script would alert "window.title is full screen on monitor A"

A few issues:

- python packages like pygetwindow don't seem to work well with dual monitors. They can't know if a window is shown/opened on a second monitor.
- Seeing if the window matches the screen resolution won't always work either, as some full screen applications have like (-1,-1) instead of (0,0) as the starting coordinates.
- Monitors can have the same resolution/screen size, so comparing the window size won't always tell which monitor the window is full screen on.

So basically, I need a function like this:

Input: hwnd of window

Output: (bool) is_fullscreen , (int) monitor_index